# Android view onClick event not passed to self

Tags: java, android, event-handling

I'm extending the EditText class in android to incorporate additional functionality one of which is to display a dialog when clicked. I want the behaviour to be portable and hence self contained.

However setting `onClickListener` to itself (this) as parameter has no effect and the function `onClick(View)` is never called.

```
public class TimePickerEditText extends EditText implements View.OnClickListener, TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    private  Calendar today;
    private TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog;

    public TimePickerEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
        postInstantiateSetup();
    }

    public TimePickerEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        postInstantiateSetup();
    }

    public TimePickerEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        postInstantiateSetup();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        postInstantiateSetup();
    }

    public void postInstantiateSetup()
    {


        setOnClickListener(this);

        today = Calendar.getInstance();

        onTimeSet(null,today.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),today.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {


        if(timePickerDialog == null) {
            timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(getContext(), this, 20, 0, true);
        }
        timePickerDialog.show();


    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hours, int minutes) {

        String hoursString = ""+hours;
        if(hours<10)
            hoursString="0"+hoursString;

        String minutesString = ""+minutes;
        if(minutes<10)
            minutesString="0"+minutesString;

        this.setText(hoursString+":"+minutesString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide some code to illustrate what you've tried.

Comment: @Submersed added relevant code